# How can I understand if roll on deodorant is about to finish?

Tags: personal-care

I use roll on deodorant and some brands have transparent cases/bottles but some others don't so I cannot see how much is left inside in order for me to buy a new one on time.

Is there any hacky way to know if a roll on deodorant with a non transparent bottle is about to finish?

An example:

[image: roll on deodorant]

UPDATE: Just realized that the picture I had posted was for a 'stick' deodorant. I updated the picture. I am talking about deodorants that have liquid inside and a moving ball on top and are not transparent like in the picture.

Comment: This problem is perhaps bigger than many might think. I have a child with learning difficulties and they are able to apply their own deodorant using a roll-on which would not be possible with a spray. Unfortunately, the level of understanding does not extend to recognition that the bottle is empty and has therefore done nothing. I therefore usually have to discard the bottle when it seems like it might be getting NEAR the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could try to "floodlight" your deodorant with a light source. What I mean is that you can put it in front of the light to make it more transparent. It should work for at least some non-transparent bottles.

I tested it on 2 deodorants with some led bulb I have in bathroom, and it helped with non-transparent white [Garnier for women](http://www.drogeria-vmd.com/imgcache/f/1/p89352-89352_285_285_26736.jpg) but it didn't with black [Garnier for men](http://www.shopfromapound.co.uk/images/garnier-men-mineral-roll-on-deodorant-cool-48-hour-protection-50ml-p246-1240_medium.jpg)

Comment: Wow...it actually works! Worked with the old spice in the above picture at least!

Answer (score 3):

If the mundane approach of buying a new one once you started the current bottle is too easy, I suggest you get a kitchen scale:

Weigh an empty bottle and a full bottle. Define a threshold somewhere between those two values that allows enough uses/time to buy the next bottle so that it fits your personal shopping frequency without actually running out of deodorant.

Then regularly weigh the current pack, especially if you notice that the bottle seems running somewhat low.

I personally always have at least one spare pack of deodorant, toothpaste and similar staples at home - and whenever I open the last pack, it goes on the shopping list.

Comment: But how do you know when you have an empty bottle? :) I think this may be the best answer we're going to get here, but it's not exactly convenient to keep weighing the bottle. I agree that it's not usually an issue, you should just open the new one as soon as the old one stop dispensing, but see my comment to the question to see why we could do with a better answer.

Comment: @Lefty I agree. Stephie's solution is a good idea but not a convenient one.

Comment: I think the first and last sentences are by far the best suggestions. Just get two, when one runs out, buy one more. Always maintain two and you'll never run out. Unless I'm confused about the issue, this is fool-proof.

Comment: Ah, I see @Lefty 's comment on the OP and didn't even think of that issue. I guess those suggestions wouldn't help in that case.

Answer (score -1):

With the bottles that have the roller in them, you can usually squeeze the bottle and the ball will pop outwards, when done checking, just push the ball into the bottle again. If you want the deodorant to last longer you could put some type of water or nice smelling oil into it at the same time (this will not work with all oils and will probably make the deodorant less strong smelling. Also, balancing the bottle upside down will cause the liquid to stick to the ball overnight making it easier to get the last bit out.